# How can I enable international keyboards on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I work in 3 different languages:

1. Swedish
2. Norwegian
3. Spanish (Latin America)

So far only the US English (non-international keyboard works), I need **at least** the US-International keyboard to work *as well as* US Standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional layouts via System Settings/Keyboard Layout. Chosing that should open a window with a list on the left, which you can extend via the "+"-button. Afaik, the uppermost entry in the list in the Settings-window is the one being used as default.

You can also choose a shortcut to switch between these keyboard-layouts via the "options" button in the same window ("Keys to switch layout"). If the Keyboard-Icon is shown in the top panel (not sure if that is shown by default), you can also use its menu entry "Keyboard Layout Settings..." to get to the aforementioned window and you can also switch between all layouts that you added to the list.